# Exchange EWS with Enterprise Vault

Tags: api, search, exchange-server, archive

Iam using EWS in my Exchange 2010 for search over a webinterface. Searching in EWS works fine.

How is it possible to search in my email archive from Enterprise Vault Veritas?

Is there a REST Service, or something like this, available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working out of the box..